# rsync over ssh get directory content only

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am trying to get files on my Raspberry Pi from a server with rsync over ssh. This is the command I have right now:

```
rsync --delete -avz -e ssh USER@SERVER:'/server/directory' '/traget/directory'
```

What do I need to add in order to only get the content from this directory witouth the directory?

Comment: you mean rsync over ssh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a '/' at the end of the directory:

```
rsync --delete -avz -e ssh USER@SERVER:'/server/directory/' '/traget/directory/.'
```